# Excel VBA - How to use change event to execute macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm learning Excel VBA so I decided to make a calculator for a game that I play. I'm having trouble getting the change event to run my macros. When I run the macro myself, it works perfectly, but when I type into cells within D3:D7 (named calc_natures1) and hit enter, nothing happens. The following code should execute my stat_data1 macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change3(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim keycells As Range
    Set keycells = [calc_natures1]

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, keycells) Is Nothing Then
        Call stat_data1
    End If    
End Sub
```

my stat_data1 macro looks like

```
Sub stat_data1()
On Error Resume Next

Select Case [calc_naturehp1]
    Case "-"
        [calc_hp1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 2, 0)
    Case ""
        [calc_hp1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 3, 0)
    Case "+"
        [calc_hp1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 4, 0)
    Case Else
        [calc_hp1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 3, 0)
End Select

Select Case [calc_natureatk1]
    Case "-"
        [calc_atk1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 5, 0)
    Case ""
        [calc_atk1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 6, 0)
    Case "+"
        [calc_atk1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 7, 0)
    Case Else
        [calc_atk1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 6, 0)
End Select

Select Case [calc_naturespd1]
    Case "-"
        [calc_spd1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 8, 0)
    Case ""
        [calc_spd1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 9, 0)
    Case "+"
        [calc_spd1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 10, 0)
    Case Else
        [calc_spd1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 9, 0)
End Select

Select Case [calc_naturedef1]
    Case "-"
        [calc_def1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 11, 0)
    Case ""
        [calc_def1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 12, 0)
    Case "+"
        [calc_def1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 13, 0)
    Case Else
        [calc_def1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 12, 0)
End Select

Select Case [calc_natureres1]
    Case "-"
        [calc_res1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 14, 0)
    Case ""
        [calc_res1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 15, 0)
    Case "+"
        [calc_res1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 16, 0)
    Case Else
        [calc_res1] = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([calc_name1], [stats_table], 15, 0)
End Select
End Sub
```

The change event code is located in the "Sheet1(Calc)" object and it affects "Calc". The code for the macro I'm trying to run is located in "Module 1" object. Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why does your worksheet_change have a 3 at the end of it?

Comment: The method signature is wrong (missing object param) so I am assuming the user tried to hand code it:  Method signature should be: Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: Have you tried debugging with breakpoints? Also remove your On Error Resume Next and see what happens.

Comment: I have 4 worksheet_changes, and this is the third one, which is why there is a three. I had them all named the same thing but got an "ambiguous" error. I saw someone on some forum did it like I have it now, so I just copied it. I'll try what @Sorceri said instead and see if that fixes anything

Answer (score 0):

The awesome @jamheadart alerted me to the fact that my worksheet_change name was incorrect. Through some more searching, I discovered that you're not supposed to have more than one worksheet change method. You're just supposed to put all the changes within the one. By copying and pasting the contents of my 3 other worksheet_changes into the first one and removing the number from the name, the macros now work. Thanks for the replies!